# Нужна ли здесь запятая после «или»?

Tags: пунктуация

"Писателям нужно сделать пост, где будет как можно больше фактов о малоизвестном персонаже и стих() или фанфик".

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна:

***Писателям нужно сделать (создать?) пост, где будет как можно больше фактов о малоизвестном персонаже и стих или фанфик.***

Если поставить запятую, то союз ИЛИ будет не разделительным, а пояснительным, как если бы стих — это и есть фанфик. Но ведь это не так?

Фанфи́к[1] — жаргонизм, обозначающий любительское сочинение по мотивам популярных оригинальных литературных произведений, произведений киноискусства.

Comment: А что скажете насчет **делания** постов? А о том, что много писателей делают **один** пост? А может, они и не писатели, раз пишут **любительские** сочинения?

Comment: Тише, тише... В эту тему лучше не углубляться. Пишут фанфики фикрайтеры, а они могут обидеться. https://модные-слова.рф/1002-fikrayter-chto-znachit.html. Могу только заменить "сделать" на "создать" или даже лучше в скобках написать.

Comment: А один пост на всех? Ведь это дело индивидуальное? Или они как Козьма Прутков?

Comment: Пост в социальных сетях – это запись, оставленная на стене личного аккаунта или группы.

Comment: Пост – это информационный блок, размещённый **пользователем** в социальной сети, блоге, микроблоге, форуме и пр.  Эти писатели выступают как пользователь (один)? и   должны сделать пост (один)?

Comment: Думаю, что у них есть возможность для  опубликования совместного сборника своих информационных записей, стихов и пр.